# Search refinement for WebMatrix site

Tags: sql, arrays, razor, query-string, webmatrix

I've been asking a few questions on this site, and have answers to lots of little bits, but I am now trying to piece the whole thing together.

I have a page where it shows all the properties I have in my database. I need to find a way to refine those results though, so for example, to only show properties that have 4 bedrooms etc. The problem is, I don't know how many variables I might have in the search term yet. So here's an example.

1. a user may want to see ALL properties that just have 4 bedrooms
2. a user may want to see ALL properties that have 4 bedrooms AND 3 bathrooms AND sleeps 8 people etc.

I have decided to pull all the variables from a query string, ?numbedrooms=4&?numbathrooms=3

Here's the code I have so far, but it doesn't work:

```
@{
var db = Database.Open("StayInFlorida");

IEnumerable<dynamic> queryResults;

int numBedrooms = Request.QueryString["numBedrooms"].AsInt();
int numBathrooms = Request.QueryString["numBathrooms"].AsInt();
int sleeps = 0;

List<int> argList = new List<int>();

if (Request.QueryString["sleeps"].IsInt())
{
sleeps = Request.QueryString["sleeps"].AsInt();
}

int numOfArguments = 0;

string selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM PropertyInfo ";

if (numBedrooms != 0)
{
argList.Add(numBedrooms);
selectQueryString += "WHERE numBedrooms = @0 ";

numOfArguments++; //increment numOfArguments by 1
}

if (numBathrooms != 0)
{
argList.Add(numBathrooms);
if (numOfArguments == 0)
{
    selectQueryString += "WHERE numBathrooms = @0 ";
}
else
{
    selectQueryString += "AND numBathrooms = @" + numOfArguments + " ";
}
numOfArguments++;
}

if (sleeps != 0)
{
argList.Add(sleeps);
if (numOfArguments == 0)
{
    selectQueryString += "WHERE sleeps = @0 ";
}
else
{
    selectQueryString += "AND sleeps = @" + numOfArguments + " ";
}
numOfArguments++;
}

selectQueryString += "ORDER BY numBedrooms DESC"; //Adjust this order by clause how you see fit.

int[] argArray = argList.ToArray();

if (argArray.Length > 0)
{
queryResults = db.Query(selectQueryString, argArray); //stores a dynamic list to 'queryResults' which can later be easily iterated through with a 'foreach' list and written to the page with razor.
}
}



<!--Results Start-->

@foreach(var row in queryResults){
<div class="container">

                <h4><a href="/property.cshtml?propertyid=@row.PropertyID">@row.PropertyName</a></h4>
                <h5>Bedrooms: @row.NumBedrooms Bathrooms: @row.NumBathrooms Sleeps: @row.NumSleeps</h5>


</div>
}
<!--Results Finish-->
```

So to clarify, I need to find a way to check to see if there is a query string entry for each search query, and if there is, append it to the SQL statement to see all results that match?

Comment: Okay, so I'll start by asking you what *you* expect to find from `Request.Unvalidated["searchText"]`. Of course, I recognize the code, but I'm not sure whether you already have something set up on the page that sends this or not. Also, when you say, "I don't know how many variables I might have in the search term yet.", is this the same variable `["searchText"]`? Like I used in the previous example? Where the user is just typing in the search bar a bunch of random words, which you separate (shown in your code above) on the other side? Is this how you expect the user data?

Comment: i dont expect anything from the Request.Unvalidated["searchText"], this was something you added on the additional post? All i want to do is search for specific querystring entries. If there is a querystring present, then add that search on the the SQL statement.

Comment: Just to clarify, all the code above was what you send over on the original post, so apologies if i don't know what each part means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mainly, what it seems that you need is a good "user-interface" page.

Within that page, you have several form input elements (radio buttons, text boxes, checkboxes, etc.), where if left blank, they are ignored, but if not, you detect and append accordingly the SQL syntax you need to the SQL string.

For instance let's just say you had this form on the first (user-input) page (let's call it `page1.cshtml`):

```
<!--[HTML]-->
<form action="~/page2.cshtml" method="GET">
    <select name="numBedrooms">
        <option value="0">Please Select</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    <select name="numBathrooms">
        <option value="0">Please Select</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" maxlength="3" name="sleeps" />
</form>
```

Of course, the viable options, and type of input fields on this form are totally maleable to your specific scenario, but you get the idea, I'm sure.

Next, in the part of the `page2.cshtml` file that begins to construct the SQL string:

```
/*[C#]*/
var db = Database.Open("StayInFlorida");
int numBedrooms = Request.QueryString["numBedrooms"].AsInt();
int numBathrooms = Request.QueryString["numBathrooms"].AsInt();
int sleeps = 0;
List<int> argList = new List<int>();

if (Request.QueryString["sleeps"].IsInt())
{
    sleeps = Request.QueryString["sleeps"].AsInt();
}

int numOfArguments = 0;

string selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM PropertyInfo ";
```

Notice that this string, if nothing else were appended to it, would work fine and simply query for all entries in the database, without syntax error (SQL doesn't mind if there is an extra space at the end. This is good to know, because it will make your life easier down the road). However, now, you can start checking to see *what* info was passed to this page from the previous, and append to the SQL string accordingly.

Also, and perhaps the easiest way, to query the database while passing the appropriate number of *unknown-until-runtime* parameters, is to pass an array to the db.Query method. So, for each parameter that we test as valid, will be added to a list and later converted to array (we use a list first, because C# does not allow you to define an array with unknown size, but a list will allow you to add values as you go).

```
if (numBedrooms != 0)
{
    argList.Add(numBedrooms);
    selectQueryString += "WHERE numBedrooms = @0 ";

    numOfArguments++; //increment numOfArguments by 1
}

if (numBathrooms != "0")
{
    argList.Add(numBathrooms);
    if (numOfArguments == 0)
    {
        selectQueryString += "WHERE numBathrooms = @0 ";
    }
    else
    {
        selectQueryString += "AND numBathrooms = @" + numOfArguments + " ";
    }
    numOfArguments++;
}

if (sleeps != 0)
{
    argList.Add(sleeps);
    if (numOfArguments == 0)
    {
        selectQueryString += "WHERE sleeps = @0 ";
    }
    else
    {
        selectQueryString += "AND sleeps = @" + numOfArguments + " ";
    }
    numOfArguments++;
}

selectQueryString += "ORDER BY numBedrooms DESC"; //Adjust this order by clause how you see fit.
```

Keep in mind that depending on how the data is stored in the database (nvarchar, int, etc.) you may have to use casting within the SQL string, parsing in C#, or simply adjust the way you write the selectQueryString, as you go, but I won't go into any further detail on that, because data types/conversions are out of the scope of this question.

Next we convert the list of arguments to an array.

```
int[] argArray = argList.ToArray();
```

Lastly, you just have to query the database. However, we also need to *MAKE SURE* that the array we sent the list to is not empty (which would most likely be caused by the list being empty when we converted it). I assure you, you will get a server-side error if you pass an empty array as the second argument to the `db.Query()` method.

```
if (argArray.Length > 0)
{
    var queryResults = db.Query(selectQueryString, argArray); //stores a dynamic list to 'queryResults' which can later be easily iterated through with a 'foreach' list and written to the page with razor.

    //put your "foreach (var row in queryResults)" loop here.
}
```

And really that's about it. The only thing is, there are a lot of things you may have to critique in order to get this working with your specific data types (as they are coming from the form page, but especially as they are stored within the database).

Comment: Hi, i have inserted your code, and updated my question above, but i am getting an error saying "A local variable named 'sleeps' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'sleeps', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else"

Comment: @Gavin5511 Sry, about that, I was trying to declare it twice. I have updated my code and removed `int` from the second occurence of the `sleep` variable.

Comment: i can't see where you've made the edit? Also, why doesn't it request a value from a query string for sleeps, but it does for bedrooms and bathrooms?

Comment: Ok, so i have updated my code in my question above. I don't seem to be getting any errors from the code block now, but i do see that my foreach statement isn't working? the error i'm getting is "'char' does not contain a definition for 'PropertyID' and no extension method 'PropertyID' accepting a first argument of type 'char' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Your foreach isn't working because you have used the wrong variable. Remember `selectQueryString` is just the string we used to query the database. When we did that we stored the returned dynamic list in `queryResults`. So, you need `foreach (var row in queryResults)` *ALTERNATIVELY*, you could just skip storing it in queryResults altogether by using `foreach (var row in db.Query(selectQueryString, argArray))` but I prefer the first approach, because you can more easily use the results again if you need, and also, I think it looks cleaner, but either way would work.

Comment: ok, so i've changed that (as i agree, let's do it the proper way), but getting this error now "The name 'queryResults' does not exist in the current context"? any ideas?

Comment: @Gavin5511 Haven't forgotten you, will look at this soon.

Comment: @Gavin5511 What you have is an issue where `queryResults` is out of scope. Try putting your `foreach` loop inside the `if (argArray.Length > 0){//put your foreach loop here}` loop, just after the assignment of  `queryResults`.  You wouldn't want your foreach loop going off if the argArray length wasn't greater than 0 anyway.

Comment: i don't understand that bit? i need the foreach loop in the body, so that foreach result i can show the information pulled from the database? How would i call that foreach information from the page body?

Comment: @Gavin5511 Wherever you tell razor to write HTML it will write it. So, instead of moving the foreach loop to the body, move the body to the foreach loop. I don't understand how this would be a problem, am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Gavin5511 Alternatively, you could initialize `queryResults` in the same place that you initialized the other variables (var db, int numBedrooms, etc.). The problem with that is that I don't remember the syntax on how to declare the appropriate variable for a dynamic list. I've been shown before, but never actually done it, and now I can't find the page where this was mentioned, but I will keep looking.

Comment: @Gavin5511 Okay, I got it. If you don't want to move the body of your html around, just initialize `queryResults` with this: `IEnumerable<dynamic> queryResults;` Do this in the same area as the declaration for your `db` variable. Then you can access it in the if loop and later down the page (i.e., you will no longer have issues with the scope of `queryResults`).

Comment: i did that, and now i get this error "A local variable named 'queryResults' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'queryResults', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else"

Comment: @Gavin5511 On which line? If you declare the IEnumerable at the top, by your `var db` declaration, you'll want to make sure that you remove the `var` from before the `queryResults` you use in the if branch. If this does not help you, maybe you can post your updated code, so I can have a look, or you can email it to me, also.

Comment: i've updated my code above. Surely it can't be this complicated, all i want to do is change my SQL query depending on whether or not there are querystring parameters present in the URL?

Comment: @Gavin5511 It's really not that complicated, at least not the part that's hanging you up. Looking at your code, I'm not sure why it would say that, but I'm still looking at it.

Comment: @Gavin5511 Do a search on the page and make sure you can account for every use of `queryResults`. As it stands, you should only find three instances. The `IEnumerable<dynamic> queryResults;` instance, the `queryResults = db.Query(selectQueryString, argArray);` instance, and the `foreach(var row in queryResults)` instance. Make sure they are the only three, and let me know if it still errors.

Comment: ok, im so lost with this, it's actually starting to really get me down :(

Comment: do you have an email address i can get you on?

Comment: @Gavin5511 I sure do, it's "cradebaugh@okmcity.net" Don't let it get you down. I've done what you are trying to do multiple times, and in the very environment you are trying to do it in. Don't worry, we'll get this :)

Comment: dude, come in the C# chat room now, we're havign a discussion on it :)

Comment: i've emailed you. i'll zip up my code and send it over for you to take a look at when you get the chance